# How to test external services?

Tags: tdd, integration-testing

We have a an application which while processing some data has to query data from a database which is not owned by our application i.e. an external application. We have put this querying logic in an external service project and the main application call this external service via http. For integration testing of the main application we have mocked out the reply of this Http service .

I wanted to know if someone can suggest an optimal way to test this external service which entails things like testing the mapping logic and the logic of the query. This service basically just queries an external database and sends back the result. We have written sql statements to get the data, there is no use of entity framework.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When testing an external service it helps if that service has repeatable behaviour.

As an example, if you can say that a specific query to the external service will always return the same predictable result then you can write a test for that.

This isn't always possible as you do not always have control over the data that the external database contains.

I would say that the best testing approaches in descending order of how good they are would be:

#### Create Test Data and Validate

The ideal approach is one where your test can create some new test data and then run the service to confirm that the data is returned as expected. At the end it will tidy up by removing the created test data.

The benefit of this approach is that you can be more confident that an external change will not break the test. You can also test specific features of the service by inserting appropriate data.

#### Validate Known Data

If the external service does not allow the creation of data the next best approach is to test for a result that you know will always be true. For example if your service was doing authentication then you would check using an account that you know exists on the service and does not change.

This approach relies on the particular data not changing. In the authentication example there is always the risk that the password is changed for the account you use to test and hence your test will fail.

#### Validate Correct Operation

The least good solution is to simply call the service with valid arguments and ensure an error code is not returned.

You can confirm that the service is up and working, but you do not gain confidence in the validity of the data being returned.

#### Non Functional Testing

In additional to testing the working service you may wish to test the failure cases, such as the service being down or uncontactable. How well does your deal with a failure in the external database? Does it recover gracefully when the database comes back online?